# Object to xml conversion: java

Tags: java, xml, performance, object

Would like to know is there any efficient way of converting the object to xml. 
I am aware of marshalling and un-marshalling the object to achive the same. but this will consume more time and is not efficient if you need the responses with in few milliseconds. 
   When we are working on systems which needs response in 10-15 milliseconds, the marshalling and un-marshalling seems to take more time and will impact the response time in 5 folds and would like to know if there is any alternate, which i can consider .

Comment: marshalling - unmarshalling = jaxb ?

Comment: You can take a look at this url may helps you http://www.infoq.com/presentations/bigdata-memory

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how complex your objects are but creating the xml string manually is always on option when looking for good performance.

Comment: Creating the xml manually, r u suggesting to use reflection for this?

Comment: If you target 10ms and a high throughput I would hardcode it if the objects are simple. Otherwise maybe reflection and cache it, but then you could probably use a library.